# How to use Flutter Firebase dynamic links with go_router

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, gorouter

I had `firebase` `dynamic links` integrated and working fine in my app and later i changed to use `go_router` and now i don't know what i should do to get it working or how to handle it.

The way i imagined it would be is that the FB dynamic link `path` will be the same as the `path` to the page in `GoRouter` `routes`, and go_router will `redirect` to the page automatically but i don't think that is how it works and i can't find any resources for this.

So the question is how to use `Firebase DynamicLinks` with `go_router`?

Answer (score 2):

this is how I did it, looks like working fine :)

- For when the app is in terminated mode:

  Future main() async {
  ...

  ```
  // Closed state: getInitialLink is Used
  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  ```

  ...

then through  runApp(MtApp(initialRoute: initialLink))  pass it to GoRouter.initialLocation field or GoRouter.redirect function, depending on how you use it.

- For when the app is in background:

wrap your top widget with a statefulWidget your created like:

class AHDynamicLinksManager extends

```
 StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const AHDynamicLinksManager({required this.child, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AHDynamicLinksManager> createState() => _AHDynamicLinksManagerState();
}



class _AHDynamicLinksManagerState extends State<AHDynamicLinksManager> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
      String goingTo = dynamicLinkData.link.path;
      GoRouter.of(context).go(goingTo);
    }).onError((error) {
      GoRouter.of(context).go("/errorpage/$error");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Hope it helped!